# Managing Rails Precompiled Asset Bloat Between Git/GitHub and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

It seems that most stack overflow posts recommend precompiling Rails assets before deploying on Heroku to avoid compilation errors and to ensure a fast deploy. However, what is common-practice on managing a long-lived repo with tons of asset bloat in Git/GitHub? I have a repo with a couple years of commits and a couple GB of git data interleaved with "precompiling assets" commits, which I feel like must not be the best-practice for this. Anyone have recommendation for cleaner way to manage the sync between GitHub and Heroku repos without polluting Git history with a ton of large ugl(ified)y files? I periodically clean the old assets but this doesn't help with managing the repo size unless I kill/squash my history, which I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: I think you are misstaken in that a majority recommends precompilation - as you have noticed there are some pretty big cons and any decent CI setup will catch compilation errors. The speed is pretty much a non-issue too - its not like you´re deploying every 5 minutes.

Comment: We precompile our asset always on heroku and we don't see any problem here. For every system we have a staging environment where you can pretest the precompilation.

Comment: @SimonFranzen what's your development process with respect to Git? Do you do feature development and then a large precompilation commit right before deploying to your staging environment? And do you clean old assets when you do?

Comment: No we don't precompile any assets before we deploy. Locally there isnt a precompilation and we let heroku do the precompilation when we deploy.
We try to keep the git repos as clean as possible

Comment: Ah got it, okay thank you